# Positioning in cross browsers

Tags: cross-browser, responsive-design, css-position

**I'm new to the front-end world and was wondering how you guys go about positioning elements on a website that translate across multiple browsers.**

I'm designing and developing a website for a school project which looks fine on my MacBook Pro in Chrome and Firefox. However, when I try to view it on IE 9 and Firefox on my work's PC, the positioning is completely off. The font size in IE 9 is also really off.

I hear IE is sometimes a bitch, but I'm wondering if there's anything I can do to make it the same across different browsers and operating systems.

I use mainly relative positioning with one or two things that are position absolute. For font sizes I'm using em's as I hear they're better for responsive. **If I want this website to be responsive and the same across different browsers and operating systems, what should type of positioning should I use?**

Answer (score 0):

I usually look at http://quirksmode.org to learn what features are compatible with the browsers that I want to support. I haven't done that in a while, but I see that the site author (Peter-Paul Koch) is keeping it up to date.

I also like to know which standards documents are relevant and what they say. As to font sizes, relevant standards include HTML 4.01 and the various levels of CSS. I think the documents don't say a lot though. In any case browsers frequently vary slightly in their interpretation of or adherence to occasional points in the standards for technical reasons. After all the standards say little or nothing about anti-aliased fonts, Retina displays, and other matters that may be very relevant to platforms and implementations.

For font sizes, I use a base size and set everything else relative to that. I haven't done that in a while, either. Other people may come along with a sharper understanding of current practices. Nevertheless I expect that my suggestion will continue to work.

When I'm coding for business purposes, then I still go through the exercise of testing in a varieties of browsers before I consider the job done.

If you had more specifics for your question, please add them. Otherwise, although it's fine that you asked here, I think you'll find that further broad "what do you guys do" questions fit in best here http://programmers.stackexchange.com

Comment: Ahhh thanks! I'm new to this board and didn't know where to ask these types of questions. Would it help if I add some of my code? This was more a general question on what type of positioning is best for coding in cross browsers and responsive design.

Comment: If you have some specific code that illustrates your question and that you could share, yes, I think we could help you better and the information would help to focus the discussion. One of the FAQs (linked at the top of each page) says that if it could take a book to answer, the question is probably too broad. If I understood your question, then I think yes, there are whole books or at least websites to address the question in all its aspects.

Comment: Here is a Plunker link to it: http://plnkr.co/edit/B7ZZs1HvEfyV4L1CVBty

I don't know how to add images and stuff to it though.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the other suggestions, I recommend you always use a CSS reset so that the default settings are similar in all browsers.

There are several good resets to choose from, I've had good success with http://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/

Good luck!